# How to retrieve numerical precision and scale of a field through SugarCRM Rest API

Tags: rest, sugarcrm

I am currently working on a project to pull data from SugarCRM. In that context I am trying to fetch the available modules and their fields through the /metadata endpoint.

Unfortunately the data from the /metadata endpoint only contains precision information for decimal fields, no info on the scale (or is SugarCRM (or me?) using precision and scale in exactly the opposite intended way?).

Field metadata of other data types like float only contains that information for fields i created myself but not for "pre-made" fields.
Currency field metadata does not contain any information about precision or scale.

How can i reliably fetch that information for all fields through the REST API?

Answer (score 1):

It's indeed the opposite way.

- `len` => precision (total number of digits)
- `precision` => scale (number of digits after the point)

Also field types have defaults for these that are used if nothing is specified in metadata.

I'm not sure what they are internally, however these are some values that Sugar Studio populates by default:

- `varchar`: `(255)`
- `integer`: `(11)`
- `decimal`: `(18,8)`
- `float`: `(18,8)`

`enum` defaults to `varchar (100)` internally, as far as I remember.

Comment: I'm aware that's hardly a easy or reliable way, sorry - I wish I knew one myself. Feel free to share if you find anything out :)

Comment: thank you for taking the time and confirming my suspicion about the precision and scale. i actually checked some of the definitions of the fields i wasnt retrieving metadata for in studio and unfortunately those fields were not configured with a default or even a consistent precision and scale at all. it seems like the whole metadata endpoint is very inconsistent in multiple ways... i hope the rest of the api is not like this too :x